# Collaborative packages organized like Wikipedia

Tags: discussion

I imagine a lot of us on this site are fans of Mathematica's design principles (for both the language and function library). When a new version is released it is always exciting for me to see what new features have been polished enough to become part of the standard library. At the same time, I don't feel that software sophistication as a whole is improving as fast as it should (when compared to say the increase in size of datacenters). I think we are the right community to start building an open source, consistent set of extended packages for the standard library functions. We could contribute in a similar manner that we contribute here on SE (short bursts of work on a wide variety of problem domains), but this would also incorporate integration and organization work (building meta-algorithms, adding tests, etc). I had some initial discussions last week on the Wikidata mailing list, but there wasn't a critical mass of programmers that are used to working in short bursts on a wide variety of problems. I think that in exchange for our extra work compared to just answering SE questions, we would help build a resource that all of us would use to accelerate and expand our coding projects in ways that we haven't even imagined.

The Wikidata discussion is called "Accelerating software innovation with Wikidata and improved Wikicode": http://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/wikidata-l/2013-July/thread.html

I have a lot more I could say about this, including specifics on how to start, but I wanted to gather some more feedback after people have glanced at the Wikidata discussion.

Comment: I have been working on a set of tools that are supposed to vastly simplify publishing one's code, keeping it under version control, and using code of others in a robust way. Some parts of these tools are ready on the prototype level, but overall this is not ready yet for even asking others to test. But this is currently my main side project, and I expect to get it to a decent shape in the next couple of months.

Comment: That sounds fantastic. I was thinking of just starting a GitHub project that we can upload package files and tests into for now and then we can deal with scale issues as they arise.

Comment: What I currently have is a Mathematica GitHub client which allows to create GitHub gists from Mathematica, as well as load them and do basic versioning. Plus, a project format, basically a project is a number of files, plus a project file written in a certain way. I've made a number of gists this way, already using this system. You can have a look [here](https://gist.github.com/lshifr/4329721) (which, being a gist, incidentally is a part of the system itself).

Comment: The system currently contains of these components: [OO extension for Mathematica](https://gist.github.com/lshifr/4266126), a [module to deal with nested rules (Mathematica analog of JSON of sorts)](https://gist.github.com/lshifr/4266516), [Github gist client](https://gist.github.com/lshifr/4267071), [A module to conveniently work with porject files](https://gist.github.com/lshifr/4298795), [a module to manage project files](https://gist.github.com/lshifr/4329721), and [a raw versioning system](https://gist.github.com/lshifr/4333909). All modules use the OO extension - I deliberately ...

Comment: ...wrote this in OO-style, since this stuff seems to be best done this way. So far, the system relies on `curl` for http requests, but I plan eventually to start using pure Mathematica functions, since now it is possible. In fact, most of these components I managed with the system itself (I mean, committed newer versions). Still, the system is a little raw, and does not yet have a UI. If you are interested in trying it, I will write an installer for it in the next couple of days, and some instructions. I will also write some rad map of what I consider currently missing.

Comment: This is probably different from what you had in mind though. The idea is that one can post projects from within Mathematica. The other part, namely the project loader that would resolve project dependencies and take into account versioning, is still missing. It would actually require another layer on top of the current gist-based VCS module, as well. Plus the UI for the project management is halfway done only. The system is mostly decentralized, while we may have a single cetral repo / wiki with links to these gists. I am off for today, can continue in chat tomorrow or later.

Comment: I've skimmed through most of your code. I haven't used Workbench and I was wondering how similar your project file format is to it. Your OO extensions could certainly be useful in various areas. I typically just inline something like Fold[#2 /. #1 &, ruleTree, {"property1", "property2", "property3"}] for parsing results I get from JSON imports, but if you have to do a lot of it I could see myself using that package. I think if lots of us start uploading to separate Gists that we should still try to associate things with Wikipedia articles so that particular functionality has a  specific...

Comment: ... place it should belong. Would I look for "nested rules" or "JSON import parsing" for that functionality? With this approach I would go to JSON.m and it would have functionality for parsing because JSON has a Wikipedia article but rule trees does not.

Comment: This sounds like a nice plan, though you might elaborate a bit. What do you mean precisely by a "consistent set of extended packages for the standard library functions". This is a rather broad. Do you have anything specific in mind?

Comment: I think we should make the highest level of encapsulation and modularity for a set of community curated packages correspond to Wikipedia articles. This way they are easy to find because they all correspond to things that are considered broadly important and match how people think about things. It would just determine a scaffold for refactoring and organizing our most popular and useful code. We can integrate code from our own projects, good answers here, or browse computer science articles by popularity until we find the most popular algorithms that aren't included in the standard library.

Comment: Then over time we will be able to build up to higher level functionality than we could on our own. Simulate[{Ball[],Stairs[]},5] In your head you can imagine a default output that could generate, but the amount of logic and details to specify sensible defaults to such terse, high-level functions and object descriptions requires a substantial amount of backing code that needs to be well organized and consistently designed.

Comment: Think about all of the assumptions we make when we read that simple line of potential code. We assume the ball is about the size of a soccer ball. We assume the initial positions of the ball and stairs don't intersect and that the ball is above the stairs. We assume we'd like to see the behavior of the system for 5 seconds. So it's sort of like we are trying to apply the design principles of the NDSolve meta-algorithm to lots of things. Or like we're making an open source Wolfram Alpha, but we aren't being slowed down by worrying about natural language processing.

Comment: If I may suggest something, consider using the [boost project](http://www.boost.org/) as a template, instead of a wiki-model.

Comment: @rcollyer I was thinking of modeling the code repository under the node js community [package portal](https://npmjs.org/). But I also think that we should first have technical means of making publishing, storing / hosting, using and forking the code convenient. This is what my tools are aimed at. I am also not sure that Wikipedia is the best format, but no one prevents us to use it as *one* of the formats.

Comment: I have created a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9718/collaboration-tools-mathematica) for further discussion of these issues.

Comment: I am not convinced that wat is a good organizational structure for knowledge (Wikipedia) is also a good structure for code. Could you please provide arguments why we should do this?

Comment: Of course I don't think we can organize all code like an encyclopedia because the computational universe is too big, but I think we can use an encyclopedia as a scaffold for a lot of functionality many people will use frequently. Here are some arguments from the philosophical to practical: our brains store associations about knowledge organized like the links within Wikipedia and perform computations using that knowledge (the knowledge I have about fluid dynamics is closely related to the logic and code I write to simulate fluids or analyze data from fluid experiments), ...

Comment: ...code snippets indexed by search engines aren't very discoverable (if you know a particular snippet probably exists you can usually find it, but if code packages were organized like an encyclopedia you could easily enhance your projects by adding extra, relevant components to a simulation or find a visualization technique that you hadn't heard of), and it would accelerate innovation because "reinventing the wheel" would...

Comment: ... happen less frequently because you know where to look to see if particular functionality exists and you could easily see what functionality needs to be added to achieve specific goals (if I see it currently only contains rudimentary ability to predict the ductility of new gold alloys and I improve the functionality to meet the needs of a project I'm working on then everyone else's projects that were using that functionality would benefit).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries My main objection to Wikipedia format is that it is nice in theory, but code development / community does not work this way. People really develop what they like or feel important, and to help that development we should IMO in the first place help the developers, providing tools that will make it easier to collaborate and share code, and use the code of others. The Wikipedia format is good to document what exists already, and also good for a particular project to document what's there and what's missing, but I think this is never a starting point in development.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Usually, people just gather together and hack something, and in the initial stages they don't want to slow themselves down with bureaucracy (which is what Wikipedia is to an extent). In other words, Wikipedia is a tool for knowledge transfer, but at the start of any development, knowledge is transferred simply from one person to another, since that is then the most effective way. Wikipedia format might help someone to join an already well-developed project, and to know what exists and what doesn't,  but starting from it seems not the right thing for me.

Comment: Hmm... so you say I can easily go from solving PDEs with `NDSolve` to reading about the historical inaccuracies of Downton Abbey in a couple of clicks, all from within _Mathematica_? Sign me up! :D

Comment: On a more serious note, I agree with @Leonid about the lack of a coherent developer community within the _Mathematica_ userbase. A year ago, I started [this github account](http://github.com/stackmma) as a way to bring people together and work on projects, share codes for SE, etc. However, that hasn't seen much traction and most people have continued publishing code under their own respective accounts (including me). I suppose I could change that to an "organization" which would make it easier for people to create/contribute...

Comment: I'm confused if you are talking about the content of Wikipedia or wiki software in general. Yes, Wikipedia only contains content that many people can agree is important. Yes, some people think it contains things that are too trivial or omits important things, but I still use it all the time. If I was routinely copying and pasting code from 5 different people to mix into various projects I would already be using your code sharing tools, but I don't find ...

Comment: ...myself using other people's code very often. Maybe Wikipedia only works because there is a critical mass of people that find writing English to be easy compared to people that find programming to be easy. I can already go from NDSolve to CategoryTraffic["British drama television series",{2013,6}] and then see how Downton Abbey compares and click on the link to the article. If NDSolve wasn't already part of the standard library I would put it in ...

Comment: ... Differential_equation.m and use the "Differential equation" article as starting documentation for people that aren't familiar with them. For the Downton Abbey article I would put code that makes a semantic character relations network associated with the show or code to import such a thing from a specialized database. Maybe Wolfram Alpha will provide that at some point, but this would be more discoverable. I used to just post notebooks to my cloud storage.

Comment: Now I've tried posting code on wiki-subpages of my Wikipedia user page. No one has vandalized or improved it. Regardless, I try to organize my code this way, and I expect I will be for a long time. This would also provide a scaffold to grow the standard Modelica library. It provides standard functionality for insulators, but if you want to build up to being able to start with a standard refrigerator this would be the easiest way. Modelica just handles the power consumption and thermodynamics of the refrigerator though.

Comment: We could then add code that provides a Manipulate interface for altering a 3D model of a refrigerator and then has a button to export it in high resolution.

Comment: I would use the criteria of all code that can be used to enhance, generate, or verify content that is already included or could meet the inclusion criteria for the associated Wikipedia article as relevant to a public, collaborative code library of this nature. I think such a library could be used to grab some starting code or quickly enhance or expand any other coding project I've ever wanted to work on.

Comment: @MichaelHale It would help if you specifically address the person you are replying to, in comments, using `@`. It will make it more clear whom your reply is addressed to, and also ping that person. If your latest comments were replying to mine, we could discuss in the chat room, although probably not today (since it is quite late for me already). But one thing I want to mention: the fact that Wikipedia format works well for one person or even a small group to organize their effort does not mean it will work for a larger community. In fact, other development communities seem to not use it much.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, my comments are addressed to any Mathematica users. No one is saying wikis work well with one contributor. The English Wikipedia has over 100,000 registered users that have made edits in the past 30 days (I'm not sure how many anonymous edits are made). The only open source software projects I track are GIMP and Blender. Blender uses a wiki for its primary documentation and GIMP does not, but GIMP does have a developer wiki for script writers that seems pretty up to date.

Comment: I'm not very interested in if we collaborate in a wiki-manner or a traditional code-review all check-ins manner, but I'm very interested in the end result, namely, a large open-source library organized like an encyclopedia.

Comment: @MichaelHale, how is one supposed to get from the article to the code? For example, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) to [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Wakebrdkid/Moving_average)

Comment: @Rojo You can't for now. It would have to get really popular first. Wikidata has an item for every article, but you still have to manually put the link and icon to Wikidata at the bottom of each article. You can also get to Wikidata by clicking the edit language links on the left side, but they don't consider it significant enough yet to make it more visible.

Answer (score 2):

How about we start with a wiki approach and then retreat by adding constraints as we run into problems? I'm hesitant to start by using Gists because I think collaboration by using forked edits will be harder than just looking at the edit history of a wiki page.

I think the first module I will work on will be for the solar constant. The article is the first result in the search engines and Wolfram Alpha just gives you the standard 1.361 kW/m/m. But what if you want to get the atmospheric solar irradiance adjusted for a specific time of year to account for the elliptical shape of the Earth's orbit? Or what if you want to get the irradiance from a specific radiation frequency interval? I will start to add that functionality later tonight.

All are welcome to start contributing! Every wiki page has an associated talk page to hold design discussions for specific modules. Place tests on a subpage of each module called "tests". I also have a section for putting utilities to import modules (put your code in a `<code><nowiki>`...`</nowiki></code>` block), run tests, etc. We can continue discussing on here ideas for moving the project to a more constrained hosting environment of course.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Wakebrdkid/Wikicode